TestWidget with InternetAddress.lookup('google.com') Flutter
I have a widget that runs
await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com') 
I have not been able to find a way to test that line with testWidget, I have not been able to find how to make a Mock with setMockMethodCallHandler and it is not possible to do it any other way.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
